# Is it safe to upcast a function pointer?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, upcasting

I have base classes `Object` and an `Event`

```
class Object
{
//...
};

class Event
{
};
```

And a typedef for a function pointer

```
typedef void (Object::*PF) (Event*);
```

And an unrelated class which stores two pointers

```
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    Dispatcher (Object* obj, PF pf) : _obj (obj), _pf (pf)

    void call (Event* event)
    {
        _obj->*pf (event);
    }

    Object* _obj;
    PF _pf;
};
```

I then have a concrete object and a concrete event

```
class ConcreteEvent : public Event
{
};

class ConcreteObject : public Object
{
public:
   void handle (ConcreteEvent* event)
   {
      // Do something specific for ConcreteEvent
   }
};
```

And then call it like this

```
ConcreteObject* obj = new ConcreteObject();
Dispatcher dispatcher (obj, static_cast<PF>(&ConcreteObject::handle));

ConcreteEvent* event = new ConcreteEvent ();
dispatcher.call (event);
```

I guarantee that the dispatcher will always be called with a correct event, i.e. I will not call a dispatcher and pass it `ConcreteEvent` when the function pointer it encapsulates in fact takes `SomeOtherConcreteEvent`

The question is: Is this guaranteed to work? Is certainly works fine in gcc 4.7 on both linux and mingw.

Answer (score 4):

From the C++11 standard, section 4.11.2:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of B of type cv T”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv T”, where D is a derived class (Clause 10) of B. If B is
>   an inaccessible (Clause 11), ambiguous (10.2), or virtual (10.1) base class of D, or a base class of a virtual
>   base class of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion refers
>   to the same member as the pointer to member before the conversion took place, but it refers to the base
>   class member as if it were a member of the derived class.

So yes, this should be safe.

Edit: so if you actually meant **downcasting:** that's also legal, according to C++11 5.2.9.12:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to member of D of type cv1 T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to
>   member of B” of type cv2 T, where B is a base class (Clause 10) of D, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to member of B of type T” to “pointer to member of D of type T” exists (4.11), and cv2 is the same
>   cv-qualiﬁcation as, or greater cv-qualiﬁcation than, cv1.
>   69

Comment: The code is using the reverse of this conversion, which is explicitly allowed by `static_cast`.  The result can only be used on an object of the member's actual class type, but the OP already said he's being careful about that.

Comment: @aschepler There's another section in the Standard for that. However, this is what is called "upcasting". The inverse is "downcasting" (when casting from the member of a derived class to the member of the base class).

Comment: It can be confusing which you call what with pointers to members, but section 4 describes standard conversions which can be used implicitly, and this code requires the opposite which cannot be used implicitly.

Comment: @aschepler But nobody is talking about implicit type conversions here. OP is curious if a **cast** is possible.

Comment: I was just pointing out that the example code in the OP contains one pointer-to-member conversion which you call "downcasting" and no pointer-to-member conversions which you call "upcasting".

Comment: I disagree though, note how the *argument* of the function changes from `Event*` to `ConcreteEvent*`. There are two conversions going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue it is *not* safe, for two reasons.

The first is that pointer to member functions can only be safely propagated *downward* (because you the `Derived` class necessarily has inherited the function from the base class whilst the reverse is not true).

```
class Base {
public:
   void foo();
}; // class Base

class Derived: public Base {
public:
   void bar();
};

using PBase = void (Base::*)();
using PDerived = void (Derived::*)();

int main() {
   PBase pb = &Base::foo;
   PDerived pd = &Derived::bar;

   pb = pd; // error: cannot convert 'PDerived {aka void (Derived::*)()}'
            //                    to 'PBase {aka void (Base::*)()}' in assignment
   pd = pb;
}
```

(as seen [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/228cv0%241))

The second is that you cannot change the type of argument *just like that*. To illustrate the issue, use `ConcreteObject: public virtual Object` and you will see that it does not work as you hoped it would.

---

Now, it does not mean that what you would like to do is impossible, merely that it'll require *a bit more*.

Ideally, instead of using member functions, you would just *fix* the signature to take both an `Object` and an `Event`, and then let it deal with manual casts if necessary:

```
using Function = std::function<void(Object*,Event*)>;

void handle(Object* o, Event* e) {
    ConcreteObject* co = dynamic_cast<ConcreteObject*>(o);
    ConcreteEvent* ce = dynamic_cast<ConcreteEvent*>(e);

    if (co and ce) { co->handle(ce); }
}
```

Or whatever casts/checks you are comfortable with.

*Note: using `std::function` for compatibility with lambdas/functors.*

Comment: Or you could make `Dispatcher` a template taking a concrete subclass of `Event` as parameter, to enforce at compile-time the promise that members are only used with event objects of a compatible type.

Comment: @aschepler: actually, `Dispatcher` looks about useless to me at the moment, so I'd rather not talk about it at all :)